# Use tuples to draw Digraph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, graph-theory, pygraphviz

I want to draw Digraph of graphviz by using a tuple list.

```
from graphviz import Digraph
from itertools import chain   

edges = [("first","sub-first"),("second","sub-second"),("sub-first","sub-second"),("third","sub-third")]
nodes = list(dict.fromkeys([ i for i in chain(*data)]))
```

As you may understand, `edges` is a list of tuples consisting of an arrow (x, y).
Plus, `nodes` are the list of unpacked `edges` without duplicates. With the data, I aim to render a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to write those tuples to a file that can be parsed by graphviz? What does the number of edges have to do with that, and if the edges are given, what is there to do about "self-loops"?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the unclear description. Yep, it's about how to use the tuples to make a graph parsed by graphvis. The thing about the number means that the input tuples can be more than the given data, but the answer below just shows how meaningless it is haha. I didn't know the way to use Digraph even in the basic way:( Anyway, thanks for your question to clarify the point of mine:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what issue you're having - for a start you don't need to define the nodes if they have edges - you can just pass the edges list of tuples to the graphviz [edges](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Digraph.edges) function, which accepts an iterable:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

edges = [("first","sub-first"),("second","sub-second"),("sub-first","sub-second"),("third","sub-third")]
graph = Digraph(format='png')
graph.edges(edges)
graph.render()
```

**Output:**

[image]